# Can't Change To Document Directory

Tags: directory, home-directory, command-line

I'm brand new to Linux, and know pretty much nothing.  I wanted to learn about the Linux terminal and started watching a video, the video showed how to switch directories and they switched to the Documents directory.  I tried both "cd /Documents" and "cd Documents" both of which said the same error message.  "No Such File Or Directory".  I am really sorry for my lack of knowledge, I hope I can get this sorted.  Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: Run `ls` to see a list of files and directories, if you have no `Documents` directory in your current location, you will get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that there is in fact a folder called "Documents" in the current directory by using the `ls` command (Linux is case sensitive for files and directories). After executing this command, you will see the folders that exist in the current directory. To see your current location in Terminal, type `pwd` and it will show you where you are.

For example:

```
$ pwd
/home/allejo/
$ ls
Development    Documents    Downloads
```

If you would like to go into your home directory in Terminal, simply type: `cd` or `cd ~/`. Either command will return you to `/home/<username>/`.